# JavaScript OOP and asynchronous methods from Chrome extension api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oop, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and its uses little blocks of text.
I made a class and each block is an instance of that class. Such that:

```
function Block(bid){
    var block = Object.create(Block.prototype);
    block.title = "Default"
    block.content = "";
    block.bid = bid;
    return block;
};

Block.prototype.setTitle = function (){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        this.title = tabs[0].title;
    });
};
```

My problem is that when I call setTitle() on a Block object the title property isn't being changed by the method; it stays at "Default". I know that this has something to do with synchronous and async methods but I completely lost on going about fixing this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `this.title` refers to closure's property rather than `Block`'s from what I can tell. Check if it's scoping issues related to `this`, which it seems it is.

Comment: @mjh If I were to do `Block.prototype.setTitle = function(){this.title = "New";}` everything works fine

Comment: Yes, because that closure's `this` belongs to `Block.prototype.setTitle`. You have two closures, not one. Therefore the last closure's `this` should be scoped to belong to outer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid further discussion, my assumption is that it's a scoping issue. Could you try wit the following code:

```
function Block(bid){
    var block = Object.create(Block.prototype);
    block.title = "Default"
    block.content = "";
    block.bid = bid;
    return block;
};

Block.prototype.setTitle = function (){

    var callback = function(tabs) {
        this.title = tabs[0].title;
    }

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, callback.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! I totally forgot that I was entering a new scope when using the `chrome.tabs.query...`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `this.title` in the callback doesn't refer to the Block instance but to the callback so you just have to declare the instance reference in a variable and use it.

```
function Block(bid){
    var block = Object.create(Block.prototype);
    block.title = "Default"
    block.content = "";
    block.bid = bid;
    return block;
};

Block.prototype.setTitle = function (){

    var self = this; // Get the reference to the instance
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        self.title = tabs[0].title;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Gyus, I'm not sure why everyone copies such a constructor, that literally creates and returns a `Block` instance.

Though the question is answered, I would suggest a following way to arrange code, preventing from a scope problem as well.

```
function Block(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = 'Default';
    this.content = '';
}

Block.prototype.setTitleByCurrentTab = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
                      this.setTitleByTab.bind(this));
}

Block.prototype.setTitleByFirstTab = function(tabs) {
    this.title = tabs[0].title;
}
```

If having 2 methods seems to be an overhead, a latter one could be transformed to a closure inside setter, as Mjh suggested.

I just wanted to highlight 2 things here:

1. minimal constructor
2. methods naming - `setTitle()` sounds like a plain setter, a client can expect an argument there, unless it knows (somehow) about implementation details